# How to move a git repository which there are files modified and not committed to another server Linux?

Tags: git

In my case, I haven't finished the development yet, but can I change my  Linux server?
I am wondering that if it's possible to move my git repository - which has a lot of files modified and hasn't been committed yet - to another Linux server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every git data is in a `.git` folder in your project root and do only reference relative path. The project (with uncommited files) can be moved safely, and the git data will go along.

You can create a tarball for easy archiving:

```
tar -cvzf ../$(basename $PWD).tar.gz .
```

This will create a `.tar.gz` file, the same name as your current directory, in the parent directory (side by side with your project). Note that you can `git gc` to cleanup unnecessary git files and optimize the local repository, therefore making the archive smaller without losing data.

Comment: Uncommitted files are not in the .git folder.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer, OP wants to move the project directory itself so everything (commited & uncommited files, and git data) will be moved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  it's sample and useful

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the entire directory as it is now, just tar it up and move it.

`cd $GIT_REPO && { tar c . | gzip > /tmp/repo.tar.gz; }`

Answer (score 1):

In every branch you have got modiffied, uncommited changes:

```
git stash --include-untracked
```

Now your git repo is in a clear status. you can check with `git status`; then change your server, clone your repo there, and:

```
git stash pop --index
```

you are now in the same position you were left it off.

See: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning